# listview to crystal report vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, crystal-reports

I'm developing a SMDR application, Now the thing I need is, I'm filtering the relevant information to list view through access Database. So i want to view the list view data in a Crystal report. Please help me. Im Using Vb2010

Thank You

Comment: Share what you've attempted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an ADO.NET data source in to crystal and report off it.  There are many, many articles dealing with how to do this, so I wont document it here.

Check out:

http://developer.emc.com/developer/downloads/CrystalReport_ADO_Dataset.pdf
http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/401c4455-a31d-2b10-ae96-fa57af5aec20?overridelayout=true
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms227354%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Enjoy!